# How do I generate the list of AD group memberships for each user from a list of AD user accounts?

Tags: group-membership

I am able to generate the list of AD groups with group type information for one user and output it to a file, like so:
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$OutFile = "C:\Temp\Reports\ADUserGroups.csv"
(Get-ADUser -Identity bobsmith04 -Properties MemberOf).MemberOf | Get-ADGroup | Select-Object Name, DistinguishedName, GroupCategory, GroupScope | Export-Csv -Path $OutFile -NoTypeInformation

I like the output of this simple coding example.  How do I augment this script to provide similar output files for multiple user accounts in an input file? It seems that I cannot use -Identity $UserAccount.